# Are the 16 linear steps of the SID Sustain and Filter Volume/Resonance steps of 6.25 or 6.666666667?

Tags: commodore-64, sid

The SID has various registers that are described as 16 linear steps: The Filter Volume, The Filter Resonance, and the Sustain of the voice envelopes.

> The SUSTAIN levels range from zero to peak amplitude in 16 linear steps, with
> a SUSTAIN value of 0 selecting zero amplitude and a SUSTAIN value of 15 (#F) selecting the peak amplitude.
>
> A SUSTAIN value of 8 would cause Voice 1 to SUSTAIN at an amplitude one-half the peak amplitude reached by the ATTACK cycle.

Now, maybe I'm bad a math, but I can't make those numbers work if I try to translate them to a 0-100% scale: If I divide 100 by 16, I get 6.25. That's a nice number because the value 8 would be exactly 50% (8 * 6.25).

But the maximum value of the register is 15 (0xF), and 15 * 6.25 only comes out to 93.75%, not to 100%.

If I divide 100 by 15, I get steps of 6.66666..., and a value of 8 gives me 53.33333...% - but the value of 15 gives me 100% as expected.

Is the 6.66...% per step correct, and the "8 equals half the maximum value" is just an approximation in the datasheet? Or did they do something special to make a value of 8 be exactly 50% and just fudge the steps around a bit? Or am I missing something obvious?

|  | 100/16 | 100/15 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 % | 0 % |
| 1 | 6.25 % | 6.67 % |
| 2 | 12.5 % | 13.33 % |
| 3 | 18.75 % | 20 % |
| 4 | 25 % | 26.67 % |
| 5 | 31.25 % | 33.33 % |
| 6 | 37.5 % | 40 % |
| 7 | 43.75 % | 46.67 % |
| 8 | 50 % | 53.33 % |
| 9 | 56.25 % | 60 % |
| 10 | 62.5 % | 66.67 % |
| 11 | 68.75 % | 73.33 % |
| 12 | 75 % | 80 % |
| 13 | 81.25 % | 86.67 % |
| 14 | 87.5 % | 93.33 % |
| 15 | 93.75 % | 100 % |

Comment: This is a difference of about 0.3 dB, which (by my admittedly superficial, non-blind ad-hoc testing) is barely perceptible, so this being an approximation seems quite probable. Also, I think there is a Spın̈al Tap joke hiding somewhere in here… who’s to say the 93.75% isn’t the ‘real’ 100%? (Okay, fine, if it’s compared to the attack amplitude, then there is a meaningful point of comparison. Still…)

Comment: @user3840170: Actually, I wouldn't be surprised if a sustain value of 15 yields a value slightly short of the peak attack amplitude.  I'd trust experimental measurements or an analysis of the die photo far more than I'd trust the documentation.

Comment: @supercat Yeah, I got hung up a bit on the documentation mentioning 8 being half and the numbers working out beautifully with 6.25 except for that pesky 100% value :)

Comment: @MichaelStum: I thought the SID was great back in the day, but often wished it had provided a means by which programmers could set the volume of a voice instantly.  Having to have each voice ramp up to a non-configurable maximum volume was an annoying limitation which seems rather needless.

Comment: @supercat Agreed that this should be settled by an oscilloscope, or at least a digital audio recorder.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

0 represents 0% and 15 represents 100%, so 100%/15 ≈ 6.67% per step is correct.
You've got 16 values (0..15), encompassing only 15 intervals.

Comment: The basic [fence-post error](http://catb.org/jargon/html/F/fencepost-error.html) in reverse.

Comment: Also the basic "I only have 10 fingers" problem :)

Comment: What does this answer add over the analysis already found within the question body?

Comment: @user3840170 It provides an answer. The question was *is it A or B?*

Comment: Based on what? Why would not the other thing be the answer?